# Find a table row and show. Table in (scrollable div)

Tags: javascript, css-tables

I have a ~200 row x 16 cell table in a scrollable div. Each row has an id which is also the innerHTML if td[0]
The table is too big to show total so it's in a vertical scrollable div for data perusal.

I was wondering if it's possible to specify a row by id and have the div scroll to show that row if it's not in view?

The built in browser 'find' does exactly this but it's not really user integrated.

No jQuery please.
TIA

Comment: add some code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about `scrollIntoView()`?

You could achieve what you want using that e.g.

```
var elementToShow = document.getElementById("YOUR_ROW_ID");
elementToShow.scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: Purrfect!
No I hadn't heard about that method. Need more study I guess.
Thanks for that!